How to reach bottom of Web page to load videos of YouTube
I was learning to automate web scraping on YouTube individual Channel.
I was automating the scrolling of web page action so that as I scroll part by part all the bottom videos should get loaded and visible, I was using JavaScriptExecutor for this as shown in the code. I was expecting the scrolling action would stop when it reaches bottom of the page or to first video that was been uploaded by user.
But the below code written got exhausted after reaching certain scrolling action, the code was running in back but the scrolling operation wasn't performed on the Web page.
I have Used JSONArray to store the description and views and days.
Here is a code:
     WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
     WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
     WebDriverWait wait = new 
     WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));
     driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@LambdaTest/videos");
     JSONArray resultArray= new JSONArray();
   try {wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-  label='Accept all']"))));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Accept all']")).click();
   }catch(Exception e)
 }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    long scrollheight =(long) js.executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight");
    long startHeight = 0;
    do{
        startHeight=scrollheight;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+startHeight+")");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        scrollheight = (long) js.executeScript(("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight"));
    }while(startHeight!=scrollheight);
    List<WebElement> allvideos= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*  [@id='contents']//div[@id='content']"));
    for (WebElement video:allvideos){
        WebElement details =video.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='details']"));

        WebElement videoTitle = details.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='video-title-link']"));
        List<WebElement> videoMetaData = details.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='metadata-     line']//span"));

        JSONObject videoData = new JSONObject();
        videoData.put("video_title",videoTitle.getText());
        videoData.put("video_views",videoMetaData.get(0).getText());
        videoData.put("video_days",videoMetaData.get(1).getText());

        resultArray.add(videoData);
    }
    System.out.println(resultArray);
}
 

For reference: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/web-scraping-with-selenium-java/.
How can I figure out the root cause? I am open to any alternative solutions.

I tried running your code as it is , its scrolling the page successfully till bottom.
Its failing when its tries to get the item from video_Meta_Data list.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

If you add wait for all videos to be visible and check that the video metadata list is not empty before accessing it, the test passes successfully.
List<WebElement> allVideos = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']")));
    for (WebElement video : allVideos) {
        try {
            WebElement details = video.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='details']"));
            WebElement videoTitle = details.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='video-title-link']"));
            List<WebElement> videoMetaData = details.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@id='metadata-line']//span"));

            // Check if meta data exists before accessing
            if (videoMetaData.size() >= 2) {
                JSONObject videoData = new JSONObject();
                videoData.put("video_title", videoTitle.getText());
                videoData.put("video_views", videoMetaData.get(0).getText());
                videoData.put("video_days", videoMetaData.get(1).getText());

                resultArray.add(videoData);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not enough metadata for video.");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element not found in video: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


Thats Works !!! ,Thank you
